# Third-person point-of-view of Pensieve

Tags: harry-potter

If you view one person's memories in a Pensieve, then how use it in a third-person point-of-view ?
I mean, since a person can't see what's happening behind him, how can that the person watching the said memory can ?

Comment: Er...., could it be that it employs magic in some fashion?

Comment: Well yeah, but it's an inconsistency, because that means the one can see something he didn't remember. How would the Pensieve get the "extra" information ? Time-travel ?

Comment: Isn't this a common trope? Like someone talking into their sleeve or alarm clock and whoever is on the other side seeing them in full portrait including the communication device? At least Harry Potter got the excuse of it being magic. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Technically he cannot, but apparently the magic of the pensieve allows it anyway. JKR I think confirmed that that's how Harry was able to listen to the Marauders in Snape's memory of his post DADA exam.

Partially it's answered here: [Do you need to erase the memory of *watching* a memory in a Pensieve?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/52397/do-you-need-to-erase-the-memory-of-watching-a-memory-in-a-pensieve)

Some interesting thoughts are also given here http://www.the-leaky-cauldron.org/features/essays/issue4/PensieveThoughts, especially the glaring example from HBP, when Hokey leaves the room yet Tom and Hepzibah continue talking and Harry and Dumbledore stay with them.