# What would happen if you were to look at a picture of a Basilisk?

Tags: harry-potter, basilisk

Would you be petrified by it, or would nothing happen? Or is it not possible to take a photo of a Basilisk?

Comment: Presumably, nothing.

Comment: Click [here](http://vignette3.wikia.nocookie.net/villains/images/1/19/TheBasilisk.jpeg/revision/latest?cb=20150104113035) and find out

Comment: @Richard Are you trying to petrify the competition?

Comment: The dupe strongly indicates that you **can't** take a photo of its gaze.

Comment: Related: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/96747/would-seeing-a-basilisk-in-a-memory-cause-death

Comment: You'd kill any pictures of yourself in existence. Bye bye Instagram.

Answer (score 2):

Given what happened to Colin's camera in *Chamber of Secrets* when he viewed the basilisk through the lens (and a ghost?), it doesn't seem like it would even be possible to take a photograph of a basilisk.

Then consider that indirectly meeting its gaze - using a mirror, for example - only petrifies rather than killing. That's still a real life basilisk, yet the effect is much reduced. Even if you can photograph one it seems like that would be even further removed from meeting a basilisk's gaze, so I don't think it would do anything at all.

Comment: I saw a film of one and I'm ok.