# Could a Death Eater hear the prophecy in a Pensieve memory?

Tags: harry-potter, pensieve

Harry Potter heard the conversation between his father and Sirius in the Pensieve memory of Snape just because Snape was nearby.

Could a Death Eater, that was near Harry and Neville when they smashed the prophecy, just create and watch their own Pensieve memory and listen to the prophecy just like Harry listened to his father?

Comment: For all intents and purposes: yes, provided the Death Eater actually heard the prophecy, has access to a Pensieve, and possesses enough skill to successfully use the Pensieve.

Answer (score 2):

Honestly, I like this question because it calls out some of the logic of the pensive.

What other answers imply is that, during Snape’s memory, Snape heard every single one of The Marauders’ words. This, I believe, is highly unlikely unless they were either having conversation extremely loudly or were right next to Snape. I seriously doubt Snape would have chosen to sit within earshot of James and Sirius.

One could argue he was focused on his paper so he didn’t hear them and the memory allowed Harry to hear the subconscious sounds Snape picked up. Well, that’s the same argument as a Death Eater picking up subconsciously what he heard from the prophecy. Unless it was physically too loud. Regardless, I seriously doubt Snape heard the whole conversation.

As conclusive evidence that the Pensieve is not restricted to an individual’s recollections of an event, Harry was able to see James’s exam paper during an examination. Unless you want to suggest Snape was such an accomplished legilimens that he could see through the minds of every person in the hall simultaneously, I seriously doubt he could’ve seen James Potter scribble “LE” onto his paper.

So, in theory, a Death Eater could’ve taken his memory into the Pensieve and either listened to Trelawney or read her lips. The real reason they didn’t, apart from protecting the plot, is because they didn’t have a Pensieve :)

Answer (score 0):

No.

How pensieve works:

1. You witness an event.
2. You put your memory of the event into the pensieve.
3. You or someone else watches that memory.

Memories are not perfect. You can't recall what you didn't remember or notice in the first place. Snape was the one who heard the prophecy so he could recall it. A Death Eater would remember an orb and how it looks and how it was smashed, but because they didn't hear a prophecy coming from the orb, they would only remember the look of the orb but not the sound of it.

Another example: Lets say I remember you wearing the blue shirt on Friday two weeks ago (possibly because of memory altering charms). I put the memory in the pensieve. In pensieve I (or anybody else looking) would see you wearing the blue shirt, because I remember you wearing the blue shirt. Even if you wore the green one in reality. Same goes for the things I didn't notice in the first place, like that spy hiding in the trees behind you. If you knew about the spy, you could recall it, but not me, because I didn't know about the spy in the first place. Maybe I'll recall that the shadow in the tree was deeper than it should be, but I won't be able to see spy's face if I didn't notice it in the first place.

Comment: This does not seem to be how the Pensieve works according to the answers here: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/52397/do-you-need-to-erase-the-memory-of-watching-a-memory-in-a-pensieve?rq=1

Comment: "So I don’t think it recreates the memory, so much as brings it to the foreground. As time passes, you might no longer be able to recall the specific details, but they’re still in there somewhere, and the Pensieve can bring them back up." You still can't see in the pensieve what you didn't witness. Lets say you see me put a book into the woodchipper. You can see that it was called "Harry Potter and philosopher's stone" but you haven't read the book. You can't open the book in the memory and read it. Same goes for prophecy. If you haven't heard it irl, you can't recreate it in pensieve.

Comment: So how could Harry then listen to the conversation between his father and Sirius? Snape did not listen (actively).

Comment: But he was there on the location and actually heard what they were saying, because he was in hearing range. Death Eaters were there on the location (ministry) and didn't hear the prophecy because they weren't in hearing range.  If they were in hearing range, they wouldn't need pensieve, they could just recall what was said. They were in range to see it destroyed, though.

Answer (score 0):

No, Snape was relativity near James and without any noise, also that he is following James and his friends indicated that he is paying attention what are saying is not a coincidence that he listen the conversation.

But even Harry who is near the prophecy when it broke cannot listen more than a few words without sense. Death eaters who are a great distance cannot listen a thing of the prophecy because they cannot hear anything.

Also memories have a limit of distance, Death Eaters are far from Harry so a memory of a Death Eater could not reach the place where the prophecy brokes.